# ¿Cómo agregar una variable a una url de botón?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Quiero generar un link de whatsapp con el nombre de una persona y hacerlo todo desde una página web.

La idea es pedir el nombre a una persona y al momento de introducirlo, el enlace hacia mi whatsapp contenga el nombre de la persona.

Y que no te permita hacer click en el botón de whatsapp si no has agregado el nombre aún. Que el campo de introducir el nombre sea obligatorio.

Les dejo una imagen con una maqueta de lo que quiero lograr hacer. 
Si se puede hacer en html sería genial, lo más simple posible.

El link es el siguiente: https://wa.me/584144416340?text=**VARIABLE**

El resultado debería ser: https://wa.me/584144416340?text=**NOMBRE**

La idea sería que al introducir el nombre, el enlace contenga el nombre de la persona. ¿Es posible realizar eso?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: lo que comentas es inicialmente un formulario html con el campo `nombre` obligatorio y un tipo de method `GET`. Que has probado hasta ahora?

Comment: hola amigo. me podrias dar un pequeño ejemplo de como puedo hacerlo? me ayudarias un monton. no soy muy experto en metodo get

Comment: edita la pregunta y añade que has probado hasta ahora. Como te comento parece que lo que quieres es un formulario html basico. Echa un vistazo a este doc para tener mas claro como hacer un formulario: https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/3339201-aprende-a-crear-tu-propio-sitio-web-con-html5-y-css3/3350285-formularios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pequeño formulario HTML con una función JS.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   function setNombre() {
    var miUrl = " https://wa.me/584144416340?text=" + document.getElementById('txtNombre').value;
    window.open(miUrl);
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  Nombre: <input id="txtNombre" type="text" name="fname"><br>
  
  <button id="btnWAPP" type="button" onclick="setNombre()">Mi url</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Lo único que hace es recoger el valor del `input` en cuanto hagas click en el botón MiUrl.
Si lo ejecutas aquí, no abrirá la ventana, haz un copy paste al bloc de notas y pruébalo ahí.
Y ten cuidado con poner tu número por ahí.

Comment: amigo asieR_2 gracias por tomarte la molestia de ayudarme. dejame probarlo. a ver que tal queda y si trabaja bien. y te cuento como me va. muchisimas gracias. eres muy amable

Comment: Amigo Funciono PERFECTO! un Millon de Gracias. Me Ayudaste Muchisimo de Verdad te Agradesco! un Abrazo Desde Venezuela.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo pero para eso podrias hacer un redireccionamiento de php 
la pagina seria

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="url.php" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
      <input type="submit" value="Whatsapp">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

y el archivo url.php seria:

```
<?php
  if($_POST['nombre']){
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
      if(!empty($nombre){
        header("Location: https://wa.me/044144416430&text=".$nombre);
      }else{ 
        header("Location: index.html);
      }
  }else{ header("Location: index.html");
}
```

Comment: hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta. como podria hacer para insertar la variable (el nombre de la persona ) a la url del boton?

Comment: aqui en header("Location: https://wa.me/044144416430&text=".$nombre);
la variable $nombre es el dato que introdujo la persona

Comment: el boton te llevara a un link php (el cual es url.php)
que si cumple ciertas condiciones (que no este vacio el nombre y que este establecida la variable nombre) entonces te llevara al link con la variable incluida

Answer (score 0):

Se que este post es muy antiguo, que seria mejor iniciar otro. Pero es que necesito ayuda con un problema identico a este, salvo que lo que yo necesito modificar es un número que está en el interior de la url:

Http://11.220.192.0:8088/u/sistem?330&write? =&x

Yo necesito modificar el "330" de la url. Con el ejemplo de arriba lo consigo salvo que no se como añadir lo que me falta tras la variable. Cualquier ayuda sera bienvenida. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Esto no provee ninguna solución a la pregunta, si tienes otra pregunta, la puedes [formular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) y añadir como referencia [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/230023/c%c3%b3mo-agregar-una-variable-a-una-url-de-bot%c3%b3n), [es mejor dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/586/por-qu%c3%a9-necesito-50-puntos-de-reputaci%c3%b3n-para-comentar-qu%c3%a9-alternativa-tengo)